# How do I import an existing PDF that has been updated by the user?

Tags: swift, pdf, nsdocumentdirectory

In my Swift app, users can import PDFs from their document directory into a tableview.

I expected that if the user updated a PDF with iOS 11's feature that allows drawing on the document, the PDF would be updated in the app. But those updates do not appear in the app, even if the user deletes the original entry and re-imports it.

Has the updated file's URL has changed somehow? How do get my app to recognize that the file has been changed by the user?

Thank you,

Eli

My didSelectRowAt:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let navController = splitViewController?.viewControllers[1] as? UINavigationController else { return }
    guard let viewController = navController.viewControllers[0] as? ViewController else { return }


    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let labelContent = cell.textLabel?.text
    print (labelContent as Any)

    //User tapped a built-in page

    if labelContent?.range(of:"✡️") != nil {
        fileIsFromService = false
        print ("It's a built-in page")

        var newURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row], withExtension: "pdf")
        path =  newURL
        newBook = path.lastPathComponent
        print ("The url to be passed is \(path)")

        indexPoint = indexPath.row
        print ("indexPoint is now \(indexPoint)")
        viewController.load(items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])

    }
    else {

        //User selected a document from the device's directory

        fileIsFromService = true

        indexPoint = indexPath.row
        let fileExists = FileManager().fileExists(atPath: (String(describing:(newDoc))))

        if !fileExists {
        let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        finalDocURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])


        path = finalDocURL
        newDoc = path.lastPathComponent
        indexPoint = indexPath.row
        viewController.load(items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])

        }
    }
}
```

My didPickDocumentAt:

```
 func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController,   didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    do {
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: url.standardizedFileURL, to: documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent))


    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    finalDocURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
    newDoc = finalDocURL.lastPathComponent

    if !items.joined().contains(newDoc) {

        userDocs.append(newDoc)
        defaults.set(userDocs,forKey:"UserDocs")
        items[4].append(userDocs.last!)
        defaults.set(items,forKey:"Items")
        tableView.reloadData()

        print ("Success")

        alertSuccess()

    }
    else {

        print ("I already have this document")
    }
    print ("I'm reloading...")
     tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Note related to your question but don't use `String(describing:)` method

Comment: And don't forget to add a `return` after printing the error or move the rest of your code below the `try` inside your `do` closure